# How to execute insert query where data to the parameters are coming from the result set of a select query

Tags: sql, go

I am trying to fetch data from one database(db) which is in a different server and insert the fetched data to another database(db1) in a different server.
So far I am able to select data from db but could not insert it into db1. I am getting Null values in the database. Any help would be appreciated.

My code snippet is below:

```
func searchHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
dsn := "server=*****.ecc4q.****.com; user id=******; password=***************"
db, err := sql.Open("mssql", dsn) 
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
err = db.Ping()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}


rows, err := db.Query("select Incident_Number, Last_Resolved_Date, Corporate_ID from ITSM.dbo.HPD_Help_Desk_Classic")
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
defer db.Close()

dsn1 := "server=******.md3q.***.com;user id=*****;password=********"
db1, err := sql.Open("mssql", dsn1) 
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
err = db1.Ping()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

for rows.Next() {
    err := rows.Scan(&Incident_Number, &Last_Resolved_Date, &Corporate_ID)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

    stmt1, err := db1.Prepare("INSERT INTO mdesk.dbo.tbl_tcktinfo(TicketNumber, ResolvedDate, CDSID) VALUES(?,?,?)")
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }

    res, err := stmt1.Exec(TicketNumber, ResolvedDate, CDSID)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    log.Println(Incident_Number, Last_Resolved_Date, Corporate_ID)
}
defer db1.Close()
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You scan records into `Incident_Number`, `Last_Resolved_Date`, `Corporate_ID` from rows like:

```
err := rows.Scan(&Incident_Number, &Last_Resolved_Date, &Corporate_ID)
```

But you pass different argument in `Exec()` function. You have to pass scaned variables to insert records into different database table.

```
stmt1, err := db1.Prepare("INSERT INTO mdesk.dbo.tbl_tcktinfo(TicketNumber, ResolvedDate, CDSID) VALUES(?,?,?)")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer stmt1.Close() // always clean up after yourself, preferably return errors here, too

for rows.Next() {
    err := rows.Scan(&Incident_Number, &Last_Resolved_Date, &Corporate_ID)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }


    res, err := stmt1.Exec(Incident_Number, Last_Resolved_Date, Corporate_ID)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    log.Println(Incident_Number, Last_Resolved_Date, Corporate_ID)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I was not aware of the concept. It worked for me.

Comment: If it works, you can appreciate my work by up vote and marked as accepted answer cheers!!! Thanks.

Comment: Move the `Prepare` call out of the loop. The whole point of prepared statements is that they are _prepared_, and you can reuse them with new values, and statements should be closed after you're done with them. Most likely, you'd also want to wrap this in a transaction

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted answer: I'd recommend you to do a few things more to ensure consistency,and handle your resources a bit more "responsibly". You are closing your DB connections, sure enough, but I'd get into the habit of treating the other resources in pretty much the same way.

Furthermore, if something goes wrong mid-way, instead of having to truncate the table and restart the process, I'd strongly recommend you wrap the inserts into a transaction:

```
defer rows.Close() // close your rows resource
defer db1.Close() // close at the very end
tx, err := db1.BeginTx(context.Background(), nil) // pass in a context with timeout or some other cancelable context if needed
if err != nil {
    return err // I'm returning, you can do as you like with this
}
stmt, err := tx.Prepare("INSERT INTO ...") // create the statement once
defer stmt.Close() // add to defer stack
for rows.Next() {
     // instead of your Camel_Snake_Cased vars, I'm using the preferred style and camelCase your var names instead...
    if err := rows.Scan(&incidentNumber, &lastResolvedDate, &corporateID); err != nil {
       tx.Rollback() // rollback transaction
       return err
    }

    if err := stmt.Exec(incidentNumber, lastResolvedDate, corporateID); err != nil {
        tx.Rollback() // again, rollback...
        return err
    }
}
if err := tx.Commit(); err !≃ nil {
    tx.Rollback() // not needed, but I add it as a habit
    return err
}
return nil
```

Now it's important to note that all those `Close()` functions, and the `tx.Rollback()` call all return errors. It's always best to *at least* wrap them in a log call like so:

```
log.Printf("Rolling back: %+v", tx.Rollback())
// and
log.Printf("Closing DB/ROWS/STMT: %+v", db1.Close()) // same for rows, stmt etc..
```